# Does Expresso Store's Australia Post Shipping Module handle International Postage

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

A client wishes to sell from Australia to the rest of the world.

Will the Australia Post Shipping Module handle this?

Or is there a better method..?

Answer (score 1):

The Australia Post plugin should correctly calculate international shipping rates.

However, the plugin doesn't have many options available (e.g. different parcel/priority types), so you will need to place some test orders to ensure it's calculating shipping rates which actually reflect your costs.